# Difference Between Bitbucket Service Hooks Post and Pull Request Post

Tags: git, post, bitbucket, pull-request

After reading the documentation I can't understand the difference between post and pull request post service hooks for bitbucket.

[Post Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/POST+hook+management)

[Pull Request Post Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Pull+Request+POST+hook+management)

I would like to push my repo from local to bitbucket, and bitbucket would send the updated code to the live server using one of the two service hooks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**POST hook** - posts to your URL whenever user pushes to the repository.

**Pull Request POST** - posts to your URL upon one of the actions (approve, unapprove, comment, create, edit, merge, decline) related to the Bitbucket's **[pull request](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Work+with+pull+requests)** feature.